# Socket in not connecting while app in idle state

Tags: ios, sockets, appdelegate

When i keep my app in idle state for 1 hour after that websocket is not connecting, I'am unable to receive data from server. Please guide me the proper solution?

**Appdelegate.m**

```
   - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
 {
   //Close websocket connection
  [[IXWebSocketDataManager sharedNetworkDataManager] closeWebSocket];
}


  - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{

//Websocket connection
if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"isLoggedIn"]==YES)
{
    NSMutableDictionary *paramDict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [paramDict setObject:@"fg" forKey:@"stage"];
    [paramDict setObject:@"1.0" forKey:@"app_version"];
    [[IXNetworkDataManager sharedNetworkDataManager] userPingDetails:paramDict];
    Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
    NetworkStatus remoteHostStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];

    if(remoteHostStatus == NotReachable)
    {
    }
    else{
        [[IXNetworkDataManager sharedNetworkDataManager] startLoadingWithOutUI];
         [[IXWebSocketDataManager sharedNetworkDataManager] connectWebSocket];
    }

}

}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"isLoggedIn"];
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

}
```

Comment: Do you know about -  `if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(setKeepAliveTimeout:handler:)])
    {
        [application setKeepAliveTimeout:600 handler:^{            
            // Do other keep alive stuff here.
        }];
    }` , This is used in the case of 'xmpp-framework' for chatting.

Comment: no, How is this working?

Comment: Add this code to app did enter background in appdelegate..and put your code into the commented section. Also remove close websocket connection code from there.

Comment: but if i keep my app idle for one hour it still close websocket na? by using this code it will remain only for 600sec? So how could i solve my solution?

Comment: I got your point. What you can do is search google for "how to keep web-socket connection alive ios" , you'll find two kinds of solution. One - 'VoIP' and other 'APNS'. I like the APNS thing, what you can do is, every-time app goes into background send a message to server with status = offline, and whenever server receives a messages it will send you a push notification. When user clicks that notification, app will come alive. I hope you got the basic idea. <<P.S - I haven't implemented it yet, Google things>>

Comment: Not in background, I'm looking for http://www.icodeblog.com/2011/09/19/timing-out-an-application-due-to-inactivity/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77999/discussion-between-the-ub-and-muhsina-muhammed).